# Django-tables2: How to ensure consistent ordering when sorting?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

When sorting the table by clicking on a header, if there are rows that have the same value, the order can not be consistent from one query to another. Is there a way to specify a "secondary" sorting criteria?

For example, when user clicks on the price header to sort rows by price, behind the scene I'd like to have ordering = (price, pk) sothat the result is guarantee to be the same, given the same queryset.

For now, I succeeded with `price = tables.Column(order_by=["price", "id"])`.
However, doing this for every column is tedious, there must be a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you always want the secondary sort to be the pk/id?

Comment: @Ben Yes, because the only point is to ensure a consistent order. The pk is the perfect field for that because it is unique.